# c# Access Printer Hardware Tab Information Programmatically

Tags: c#, printing, usb, wmi, device-manager

Is there a way to get the listed "Device Functions", as shown in the attached image through c#?

Furthermore, I am trying to retrieve via c# the Universal Serial Bus controller for a specific printer, which in this case is "USB Printing Support".

I have attempted to use WMI classes, but did not manage to get a common value between the classes.

[InformationToAccess.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQJyc.png)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The information about network printers is present at regkey. Please check at below mentioned location

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\Client Side Rendering Print Provider\Servers\printserver\Printers

Client Side Rendering
DsDriver
DsSpooler
PnPData
PrinterDriverData

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\Client Side Rendering Print Provider\Servers\printserver\Printers\<printer guid>\PnPData
```